# export table to pdf using jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, pdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a html table

```
<table id='print' class='table table-bordered' style='width:100%'>
    <thead>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><h3><center><img src='". plugins_url('menu-pages/logos/'.$logo.'', __FILE__)."' />".$get_r[0]->value."</center></h3></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Roll No</td><td>$stid</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Center Code</td><td>Center Code</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Language</td><td>".ucfirst($get_s[0]->language)."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>".$get_s[0]->name."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Father's Name</td><td>".$get_s[0]->fname."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Mobile No</td><td>".$get_s[0]->mobile."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>State</td><td>".$get_t[0]->name."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>District</td><td>".$get_u[0]->districtname."</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><center>".$get_r[2]->value."</center></td></tr></thead></table>
```

I want to export it to pdf using `autotable`

I am using following code

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#print').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    } );
} );
</script>
```

When I am running this then it is showing

```
No data available in table
```

What mistake I am doing please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped the whole table in a `thead` tag and that's why DataTable thinks there is no data. 
You need to wrap the header rows with `thead` and wrap the data rows with `tbody`

You will also need to make sure your table is well-formed and has the same number of columns in each row or you will get other errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="print" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%" border="1">
 <tbody>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><h3 img src=". plugins_url('menu-pages/logos/'.$logo.'', __FILE__)."><center>".$get_r[0]-value."</center></h3>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Roll No</td>
    <td>$stid</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Center Code</td>
    <td>Center Code</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Language</td>
    <td>".ucfirst($get_s[0]->language)."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>".$get_s[0]->name."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Father's Name</td>
    <td>".$get_s[0]->fname."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Mobile No</td>
    <td>".$get_s[0]->mobile."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>State</td>
    <td>".$get_t[0]->name."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>District</td>
    <td>".$get_u[0]->districtname."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'><center>".$get_r[2]->value."</center></td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
```